# Android Mapbox - Can't add id to map annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to add point annotations to my map and I need to give each of them an ID. However, I can't seem to be able to do that, because:

1. PointAnnotationOption does not have a method to add an ID
2. PointAnnotation has an id property but it's not reasignable and also I can't add a list of type PointAnnotation to my PointAnnotationManager.

My code is as follows:

```
fun addFriendLocationMapPoints(friendsLocationsList: ArrayList<FriendLocationResponseItem>,mapView: MapView) {

val sourceOptions = AnnotationSourceOptions(clusterOptions = ClusterOptions())

val config = AnnotationConfig(annotationSourceOptions = sourceOptions)

val pointAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.createPointAnnotationManager(config)

val annotationOptions = mutableListOf<PointAnnotationOptions>()

friendsLocationsList.forEach { friend ->
    val annotationOption = PointAnnotationOptions()
        .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(friend.currentLocation!!.longitude, friend.currentLocation.latitude))
        .withIconImage(bitmapFromDrawableRes(R.drawable.ic_default_friend_pfp)!!)

    annotationOptions.add(annotationOption)
}

pointAnnotationManager.apply {
    addClickListener(
        OnPointAnnotationClickListener {
            false
        }
    )
}

pointAnnotationManager.create(annotationOptions)
}
```

I know there's an easy way to do this on iOS but I had no luck making it work on Android. Anybody had a similar issue?